# Samba-share is not writable

Tags: samba, log, logging, smb

I have created a Samba-share which works fine except the fact that the files are not writeable.

The server is an Ubuntu-system with following entry in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[poddycds]
path = /mnt/hdcd/home/login/poddy/poddydata/cds
public = yes
writeable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = yes
public = yes
```

The client is a Fedora 21 system with following entry in /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.244/poddycds          /mnt/poddycds           cifs    guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,noperm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777          0 0
```

The share is mounted properly to /mnt/poddycds and I can see all files have write permission 8user, group and world) but when I try to write one of the existing files, this fails.

Any idea what could be missing here?

Update: it seems to be a problem of the server configuration, when I connect from a Windows device, I have the same problem. So any idea why the server does not mount it writeable as specified in smb.conf? Or which logfiles could I check to find the reason?

Comment: I've struggled with similar issues.  Check the permissions on the directory on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this (Its a dirty work around as you shouldn't give 777 permissions lightly)

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/share
```

Here is an [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) from the Ubuntu website explaining different file/folder permissions